# Duplicate symbols in regular expressions

Tags: regex

I make a java program and need to check if a string has a substring of three or more same letters.

If I write `[a-z]{3,}` then it's true for any string of three and more letters, even if they are not the same.

For example I have these strings: `"abcd"`, `"qwer"` and `"aaabb"`. `[a-z]{3,}` fits all of them and I need an expression that fits only `"aaabb"`.

So please tell me how do I write such a regular expression?"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you only want to check for ASCII letters, use

```
([a-z])\1{2}
```

If you want to check for any repeated character, use

```
(.)\1{2}
```

In both cases, `\1` is a backreference to the contents of the first capturing group (constructed by `(...)`), so `\1{2}` matches two repetitions of whatever was matched by `([a-z])` or `(.)`.

Be careful to double your backslashes in a Java string:

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("([a-z])\\1{2}");
```

Answer (score 4):

Use capture

```
([a-z])\1{2}
```

This captures the letter and then requires two of the capture letter after it