# Regex detect chars duplicates

Tags: javascript, regex

I use expression to detect duplicate one char in string.

```
if (str.replace(/[^@]/g, '').length > 1) {...}
```

Now, i wish detect duplicate more than one char.

For sample, lets try detect duplicates of @ or #:

```
Wordwithone@here - match

Word@withduplicate@here - not

Word@withoneandone#here - match
```

Is it possible with regexp detect duplicate char from set of chars? (@# as in sample)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15817757/duplicate-symbols-in-regular-expressions

Comment: Yes, think thats i need! Will try.

Comment: @blue112 I don't think `\1` is  valid in javascript (from the duplicate post link). never heard of that. It looks like it is related to java.

Comment: Tested. str = 'a@b@c@fsdfsd'; if (str.match(/([@])\1{2,}/ig) != null) { ... } not match.

Comment: @Mr_Green: JS regex supports (basic function of) backreference.

Comment: Why is the first one a match? I don't understand your question.

Comment: Coz only one @. No duplicate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your attempt in the comment `/([@])\1{2,}/ig` will search for **consecutive** `@` in the string.

It only needs a simple modification to make it work:

```
/([@#])[\s\S]*?\1/.test(inputString)
```

Either `[\s\S]*?` or `[\s\S]*` would work, just that the order of searching would be a bit different:

- `*?` is *lazy*, so the search for duplicate will start from the adjacent character.
- `*` is *greedy*, so the search will start from the last character in the string.

The point is to allow any number of characters to come in-between the 2 duplicates `[\s\S]*`. I used `[\s\S]` to allow any character, as opposed to `.` which excludes the following new line characters: `\n`, `\r`, `\u2028` and `\u2029`.