# Regular expression to check any character in more than two times

Tags: javascript

I'm looking for a simple regular expression to match same character in the string more than two times likes following in java script. (Number 1 is three times)
112561

Comment: I'm not sure if Regex is the best choice for this.

Comment: Just numbers or any character? Have you tried anything or done any research yet?  How about [Regex detect chars duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18506196/regex-detect-chars-duplicates) and add an extra `\1` backreference?

Comment: Just numbers in the string

Answer (score 1):

You could check if a group is more than tow times in the array.

```js
console.log(/(.).*\1.*\1/g.test('12561'));
console.log(/(.).*\1.*\1/g.test('112561'));
console.log(/(.).*\1.*\1/g.test('2125611'));
```

Comment: This expression does not match leading characters, if there are any. For example: 2125611

Comment: @COOL_IRON, it should work now. please see edit.

Answer (score 0):

The following regex can be used for this purpose:

```regex
.*(.).*\1.*\1.*
```

Answer (score 0):

This will check if a character is repeated more than 2 times in a string. Note that this also does not use `*` which is a cause for performance issues in JavaScript.

```js
console.log(/.+?(.)((?:.)+?\1){1,}/.test('abcZdefZghiZ'))
console.log(/.+?(.)((?:.)+?\1){1,}/.test('112561'))
console.log(/.+?(.)((?:.)+?\1){1,}/.test('12561'))
```